# For lossless video compression, which is better? crf or qp?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-compression

I have a raw video. I need it to compress it losslessly. There are two ways to do this. Setting the parameters `crf` or `qp` to 0. `crf` achieves constant bitrate while `qp` has constant quantization. I've two questions:

1. Do the options `-crf 0` and `-qp 0` achieve the same result (lossless compression)?
2. If not, what is the difference? Which is recommended to have lossless compression?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40668616/3337089) asks about `crf` and `qp`, but doesn't talk about lossless compression.

Comment: Are you also king about truly lossless, or visually lossless?

Comment: Truly lossless compression.

Comment: For 8 bit x264 it is the same, for 10 bit CRF of minus 12 is lossless or qp 0.

Answer (score 1):

x264 binary itself mandates that only qp 0 is true lossless, because for 8 bit x264 it is the same as in ffmpeg from 0 to 51, for 10 bit CRF of minus 12 is lossless or qp 0. But ffmpeg has changed level of crf for 10 bit from -12, 51 to 0, 63. They also seem to forget that for 10 bit high 10, high422 profiles do not support lossless, only high444 does. So for 10 bit in ffmpeg only qp 0 is true lossless, crf 0 can fail if (and it is possible, see https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/9573#comment:11) ffmpeg will go to high 10.